# Server side rendering not working with modules lazy loading angular 12 on live server

Tags: node.js, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular12

On the localhost module, lazy loading is working fine, showing meta tags and HTML content in `<app-root><app-root/>` in the view page source, but it is not showing on the live server. On the live server, I can only see meta tags and HTML contents of components that are direct children of `AppModule` but lazy loaded modules components are not showing meta tags and HTML. This weird behavior is only on the live server.

**app.server.module.ts**

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { AppModule } from './app.module';
    
    @NgModule({
        imports: [AppModule, ServerModule],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppServerModule { }
```

**main.server.ts**

```
import '@angular/localize/init'
import '@angular/platform-server/init';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
export { renderModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

**server.ts**

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { createWindow } from 'domino';
import 'localstorage-polyfill'
import 'localstorage-polyfill'
const scripts = readFileSync('dist/clientWeb/browser/index.html').toString();
const window = createWindow(scripts) as any;
(global as any).window = window;
(global as any).document = window.document;
(global as any).Event = window.Event;
(global as any).KeyboardEvent = window.KeyboardEvent;
(global as any).MouseEvent = window.MouseEvent;

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/clientWeb/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();
(global as any).localStorage = localStorage;

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule, HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppLayoutComponent } from './shared/layout/app-layout/app-layout.component';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { Tradesmanapplayout2Component } from './shared/layout/tradesmanapplayout2/tradesmanapplayout2.component';
import { Supplierapplayout2Component } from './shared/layout/supplierapplayout2/supplierapplayout2.component';
import { Userapplayout2Component } from './shared/layout/userapplayout2/userapplayout2.component';
import { AppDasboardHeader2Component } from './shared/layout/app-dasboard-header2/app-dasboard-header2.component';
import { AppDasboardFooter2Component } from './shared/layout/app-dasboard-footer2/app-dasboard-footer2.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'resetpassword',
    component: AppHeaderLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./common/resetPassword/resetpassword.module').then(m => m.ResetpasswordModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'Supplier',
    component: Userapplayout2Component,
    loadChildren: () => import('./supplier/supplier.module').then(m => m.SupplierModule),
    
  },
  {
    path: 'User',
    component: Userapplayout2Component,
    loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule),
  
  },
  {
    path: 'MarketPlace',
    //component: UsersApplayoutComponent,
    //component: AppHeaderLayoutComponent,
    component: Userapplayout2Component,
    loadChildren: () => import('./marketplace/marketplace.module').then(m => m.MarketplaceModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'User/Agrements',
    //component: AppLayoutComponent,
    component: AppHeaderLayoutComponent,

    loadChildren: () => import('./agrements/agrements.module').then(m => m.AgrementsModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'HWUser',
    //component: AppLayoutComponent,
    component: AppHeaderLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./HelpAndFAQ/helpQuestion.module').then(m => m.HelpQuestionModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'Tradesman',
    component: Userapplayout2Component,
    loadChildren: () => import('./trademan/trademan.module').then(m => m.TrademanModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuardTradesmanService],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuardTradesmanService]
  },
  {
    path: 'ContactUs',
    //component: AppLayoutComponent,
    component: AppHeaderLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./contactUs/contactUs.module').then(m => m.ContactUsModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'landing-page/liveleads',
    //component: AppLayoutComponent,
    component: AppHeaderLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./landing-page/liveleads/liveleads.module').then(m => m.LiveleadsModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'landing-page',
    component: AppHeaderLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./landing-page/landing-page.module').then(m => m.LandingPageModule)
  }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppLayoutComponent,
    AppDasboardHeaderComponent,
    AppDasboardFooterComponent,
    AppLeftmenuComponent,
    AppcommonfooterComponent,
    SupplierLayoutComponent,
    TrademanLayoutComponent,
    TrademenuLeftComponent,
    SupplierLeftmenuComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    NgbModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: false }),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxImageCompressService,
    Events,
    Title,
    metaTagsService,
    ShareService,

  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Deployed Web.config on IIS**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\HW.Web2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />

<rewrite>
   <rules>
        <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="iisnode"/>
        </rule>
       
        <rule name="StaticContent">
             <action type="Rewrite" url="{{REQUEST_URI}}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
             <conditions>
                  <add input="{{REQUEST_FILENAME}}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js"/>
        </rule>
   </rules>
 </rewrite>
 <iisnode devErrorsEnabled="false"
  debuggingEnabled="false"
   loggingEnabled="false" 
   nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />

    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What backend stack are you using? ASP.NET Core, nodejs express?

Comment: @Pieterjan I am using ASP.NET Core as a backend stack

Comment: Thanks. Do you get errors in the Visual Studio Output window when a page is server-side-rendered? Usually if the page is only partially rendered, you should see smth there

Comment: Also, is your angular app a PWA (eg through `@angular/pwa`)?

Comment: @Pieterjan i am also suffering from same issue.

Comment: Hi @Shakir. Can you also answer the above 2 questions? 1) Errors in Output window 2) are you using `@angular/pwa`?

Comment: @Pieterjan I am not using PWA and also got no error

Comment: Another possibility is that if you use .NET Core 3.1 or lower, you can NOT use an `async` delegate for `SupplyData`. So not `options.SupplyData = async (context, data) => { ... };`. This will also cause what you're seeing

Comment: @Pieterjan Also problem is that it is not working on static HTML page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242128/discussion-between-pieterjan-and-shakir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons why the body tag of your angular app fails to render on the server side. Here's a checklist:

- First make sure your live environment supports NodeJS. Without NodeJS on the server, you can't use server-side rendering
- In Visual Studio, try changing your `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable from `DEVELOPMENT` to `PRODUCTION` and run your application. In some cases the app behaves differently in either configuration (looks for the `main.js` file in another location when `PRODUCTION`). After starting the debugger and trying to prerender a view, you may see some exceptions in the **Visual Studio Output window**.

  - In my case the `main.js` file had to end up at `ClientApp/dist/main.js`. So I had to modify `angular.json` changing the `projects:ClientApp:architect:build:options:outputPath` to `dist` ([see also](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-6df7adacbdaa#67ed))
- If you experience this problem using Visual Studio, do always look at the **Output window** for errors which will point you in the right direction.
- If you're hosting a PWA (for example through `@angular/pwa`), then it's totally normal that you're getting an empty page when going to **View source** in the browser. If you'd then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, you'll be bypassing the angular service worker which shows you the prerendered html source. This is something you shouldn't bother about. Google, Bing, ... will actually fetch and index the server-side rendered version of your page.
- If you're using ASP.NET Core 3.1 or earlier, you cannot have an `async` lambda for your `SupplyData` delegate. `SupplyData` is not a `Func<Task>` and is [not being awaited in the source code of ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Middleware/SpaServices.Extensions/src/Prerendering/SpaPrerenderingExtensions.cs#L162). [I changed this in my port to .NET 6](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering/Prerendering/SpaPrerenderingExtensions.cs#L175)

```
options.SupplyData = async (context, data) => { ... };
```

- Some live environments block webrequests sent by your angular application during SSR, back to your server. In this case you will get an internal server error (500). You need to solve this by using `OnSupplyData`.

Comment: Pieterjan Thank you very much I have sorted out issue after reading your comment, issue was with outputPath so I set it to "outputPath": "dist", and also with deployed file structure.

Comment: I am facing an issue regarding deployed web.config file, actually everything is working fine for SSR application but Asp.net Api is not working and I am receiving 404 error in console but when I edit web.config file and remove iisnode and main.js related stuff then API starts working but SSR application stops. I have edited my question and add my web.config file, can you please guide me what is the issue with my web.config so that both things should work,

Comment: Can't tell, but [here's my web.config](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/web.config) which does work for the angular app and the api

Comment: Can you please share your deployed web.config that is on IIS as this web.config is there in your repository code but did not work for me.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but there's really no point in doing that. Nothing's different from the source `web.config` except the `handlers` and `aspNetCore` xml-tags